# Motorola XT180 not charging

Tags: ht, repair, battery-charging, motorola

Some months back I bought a pair of XT180s and they've worked great. The problem is that it seems one of them was not charging all this time (I was wondering why the charging station only lit the light for one of the radios but not the other but I did nothing about it). Today finally the battery ran out.

So I have two questions:

**How do I access the battery pack in them?** I can't seem to figure it out, and manual is not very helpful:

> 1. To remove the battery compartment door, press the tab at
>      the bottom of the compartment door.
> 2. Install the NiMH batteries into the battery compartment.
> 3. Replace the battery compartment door.

And there is not even a diagram as to where the compartment door may be, ugh!

**How do I fix the problem?** I can likely replace the battery; I should have a suitable replacement somewhere assuming that I can open it up somehow, but that's hardly a fix. Should I return them to the store?

Comment: If they are still under warranty and the store is within driving distance, then why not return them to the store for an exchange?

Comment: @MikeWaters annoyingly not within driving distance and I somehow need two working radios for the upcoming weekend, so ideally looking for a faster solution.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer the final question: "Should I return them to the store?"

Yes.

If they are still under warranty, return them and get a replacement.

If the battery is a sealed unit inside, then opening them might void the warranty - and if it's not, then chances are it's the charging circuitry that has failed.

Return them and get a replacement - I don't know why you even have to ask. Faulty goods == return.

Answer (score 0):

Is this clip that you need to access the battery?

[image]

Comment: What else could it be for?